# How do I remove the leftmost zero (on the x-axis) when graphing a categorical variable?

Tags: stata

`hist body, discrete freq xlabel(#5, labsize(small) angle(forty_five) valuelabel)` produces:

[image: Graph]

I'm graphing a categorical variable, but I can't figure out how to drop the zero from the x-axis. I've tried the documentation for `xlabel()` and `xscale()` but didn't find any winners.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to spell out that you only want `xla(1/5,` stuff `)`. How to spell out precisely which labels you want is documented.

Not the question, but this is in my view a poor graph. Go with a horizontal bar chart in which (1) the discreteness of the variable is respected;(2) the category labels are properly and readably horizontal, instead of using a most awkward device of text at 45 degrees. `catplot` (SSC) is one way to go. Also in Stata 13 (updated) upwards, `graph hbar` will do as well. You should also split the title in two lines. Even further off-topic: most consumers of this research should not care two hoots about the variable name or its question number in your survey.

Comment: The key part being to replace "#5" with "1/5". Thanks for your help! As for the rest, the above graph was never meant as a production copy.